# How to trigger a dbms_scheduler job from Java repo in Spring?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, dbms-scheduler

I have an Oracle DB Scheduler job that I'm able to run directly using command:

```
EXEC dbms_scheduler.run_job('MY_SCHEDULER_JOB');
```

Now I'm trying to invoke the same job from my Java SpringBoot service where I'm using *JDBCTemplate* in Repo to run Select and Update queries on the DB.

I've looked and not found any help on how I can do this. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `SimpleJdbcCall` for this purpose

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate());
simpleJdbcCall
      .withCatalogName("dbms_scheduler")
      .withProcedureName("run_job")
      .execute(new MapSqlParameterSource("JOB_NAME", "MY_SCHEDULER_JOB"));
```

Btw, you can pass here

> A job name or a comma-separate list of entries, where each is the name
>   of an existing job

so this is also valid case :

```
new MapSqlParameterSource("JOB_NAME", "JOB1, JOB2, JOB3")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it ran into the below error.
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for 'RUN_JOB' `

I tried to create an SP that would run the job, but that doesn't seem to work either. The SP doesn't compile.

Comment: try using `.withSchemaName` instead of `. withCatalogName `

Comment: Tried that, fails with the same error. It appears that the oracle package dbms_scheduler is not accessible this way. Is there a way to access this package, its only then we'll have access to the run_job SP inside.